# How to make a gaussian blur effect in UDK

Tags: udk, unreal, blur, shaders

I want to make a plane shape (surface) that have a gaussian blur applied to it and this plane is transperant, so all objects behind it looks like they are having a gaussian blur effect.

Answer (score 1):

The [pros at Polycount](http://www.polycount.com/forum/showthread.php?t=87743) have a good discussion of this topic, as well as how to achieve related effects such as frosted or textured transparent materials.

The long and short of it is, take a look at the material's distortion input.